# Fading Nodes Along edge using `\draw`

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

How can i make nodes along an edge fade, here is the code i used to create the nodes

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\listfiles
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed,blue](0,0)--(7,0.5)
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,draw=black](0)[pos=0]{} 
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,](2)[pos=0.1]{} 
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.8](3)[pos=0.2]{} 
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.7](4)[pos=0.3]{}
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.6](5)[pos=0.4]{}
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.5](6)[pos=0.5]{}
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.4](7)[pos=0.6]{}
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.3](8)[pos=0.7]{} 
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=0.2](9)[pos=0.8]{}  
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt](1)[pos=0.9]{}
   node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt](10)[pos=1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this code, i tried to use `opacity` option for nodes, but the output edge was drawn ON the nodes as shown. I want to make it appear as if the nodes are connected with this line not the line drawn on them.
[image: code output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have two options, either you mix the color with white to fake the opacity or indeed you don't connect them with a single line but draw each segment separately

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path(0,0) -- (7,0.5) \foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {0,0.1,...,1}{node[fill opacity={1-\x},circle,blue,pos=\x,fill] (n-\xi) {}};
\draw[blue,dashed]\foreach \x[count=\xi from 0,count=\xj from 1] in {0,0.1,...,0.9}{(n-\xi) -- (n-\xj)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `(n-\xi)` the name of the node?, if i need to use it,  can i use (n1,n2,...)?

Comment: @misa  You can use `(n-1),(n-2)...`